# Print Uncommon characters in the two strings using Map and List Iterator

Tags: java

### ***Need this code to be done by ListIterator***

### input :

> String 1 : abcd String 2 : abcde

### output : e

I tried solving this approach in different ways, but i wasn't able to do it by using Map annd listiterator

```
class Solution  
{  
    static int MAX_CHAR = 26;     
    static void findAndPrintUncommonChars(String str1,String str2)  
    { 
        int present[] = new int[MAX_CHAR]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)  
        { 
            present[i] = 0; 
        }     
        int l1 = str1.length(); 
        int l2 = str2.length(); 
             
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) 
        { 
            present[str1.charAt(i) - 'a'] = 1; 
        }       
         for (int i = 0; i < l2; i++) 
        {                    
            if (present[str2.charAt(i) - 'a'] == 1
                || present[str2.charAt(i) - 'a'] == -1)  
            { 
                present[str2.charAt(i) - 'a'] = -1; 
            }                
            else
            { 
                present[str2.charAt(i) - 'a'] = 2; 
            } 
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) 
        { 
            if (present[i] == 1 || present[i] == 2)  
            { 
                System.out.print((char) (i + 'a') + " "); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: can you add more details about *uncommon* characters?

Comment: For example, in String 1 : abcd, String 2 : abcdefg
Output should be unmatched characters in two strings. i.e output for this example : efg